# Facebook graph api returns empty result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull user feeds from facebook, But the array of result i am getting is empty. The code i am using is

```
$jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$user_id}/feed?limit=25&access_token={$access_token}";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$user_data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($user_data);
```

The result always getting is

Array ( [data] => Array ( ) )

Can anyone help me to find what the issue is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your give code in my php code.
It is working find. Please check that the **USERID** which you are posting has a feed.
To test try **BMW**, **FACEBOOK** userid so you can find the feeds.

Try below url you will get its feed.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/BMW/feed?limit=25&access_token={$access_token}
```

Comment: As per the new policies by facebook, i need to submit the app for review to get the read_stream permission to fetch the feed. That may be the problem here i think. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: There is no need to apply for the read_stream permission. I also didn't apply for the same.
Use apptoken(APPID|APPSECRET) in access_token. You will get the result.

Comment: I have checked the access token generated by the api request in Access Token Debugger and the scope it showing is public_profile only. But i have set scope as read_stream in my code. It is not applying for the token. I can generate the token manually in Graph API explorer with read_stream permission. With that access token i can fetch the feeds